# Jquery hover with ul

Tags: jquery, menu, html-lists, onmouseover

I'm trying to make a basic hover on a ul element, which would display the li element. 
I've tried something here : http://jsfiddle.net/ExWQp/3/

The problem is that when i leave an li element for another one, the function mouseout is activated.

Can you help me on this ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.ssmenu').hover(function () {
    $('.ssmenu li').fadeIn();        
},
function () {
    $('.ssmenu li').fadeOut();        
});    

$('.collections').bind('mouseover', function () {
    $('.ssmenu li').fadeIn();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExWQp/4/

Comment: I commented out excess code at the end (and formatted the code to comply the Google coding standards)

Comment: @user1056832 - Your problem was the type of event handlers you were using are effected when you mouseover an internal element of that element you're moused over.

Comment: Oh I see, you took the `.collections` `mouseenter` event handler out altogether.

Comment: Dimitry, please post your actual code with at least a brief enough explanation of what you did to resolve the problem in the code you've provided. Giving a link and "I don't, what do you think?" isn't a particularly great answer to want to upvote.

Comment: No problem; I did give you the upvote. I was thinking along the lines you were, I just didn't spot the specific problem with `.collections` that you did. So good job.

Answer (score 2):

Use `$.mouseenter()` and `$.mouseleave()` instead of `$.mouseover()` and `$.mouseout()`.

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    var $menulist = $('.ssmenu'),
        $menuitems = $menulist.find('li'),
        $colls = $('.collections');

    var hoverin = function() {
        $menulist.fadeIn();
    };

    var collenter = function() {
        $menuitems.fadeIn();
    };

    var menuleave = function() {
        $menuitems.fadeOut();
    };

    $menulist
        .hover(hoverin, menuleave)
        .bind('mouseleave', menuleave);

    $colls.bind('mouseenter', collenter);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/ExWQp/6/